# Can I use Syncfusion Metro Studio 2 icons anywhere?

Tags: license, modern-ui

I've been looking about it for a while and I'm quite sure that they say I can freely use those icons on any win8, .net app etc. But how about normal, regular website or some reselling puropses like website themes etc.

Anyone is quite sure how is it looking in those cases?

[Here is official website](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as stated in the FAQ on that page, you can use them anywhere.

> **Where can these icons be used?**
>  Metro is a design language so it can be
>   applied to **any platform or technology**. At Syncfusion we have used
>   these icons in **everything from PowerPoint presentations to applications**...